# Using regex for validating a password in python web.py form validation

Tags: python, regex, forms, validation, web.py

I am using python web.py framework for designing small web application, and trying to validate password field with concept that `Password length must be more than five characters.`

According to the web.py framework we can write regex for validating password field and 
below is my code

```
render = web.template.render('templates/')


urls = (
  '/login',   'Login',
  '/projects',  'Projects',
  '/project_details',  'Project_Details',  
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
vpass = form.regexp('Must be more than 5', lambda x:int(x)>5)

class Login:

        login_form = form.Form( 
        form.Textbox('username', form.notnull),
        form.Password('password',vpass, description="Password"),
        form.Button('Login'),
        )

    def GET(self):
        form = self.login_form()
        return render.login(form)

    def POST(self):
        if not self.login_form.validates():
            return render.login(self.login_form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

But when i click on login button no message is displaying on browser "`password length must......`" .

Whether above regex working ?

How to implement password validation in web.py frameowrk

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `Validator`, not a `rexexp` object:

```
vpass = form.Validator('Must be more than 5 characters', lambda x:len(x)>5)
```

A `rexexp` object expects a python regular expression as the first argument, and an error message as the second argument. A password validating regular expression would be something like:

```
vpass = form.regexp('.{6,}', 'Must be at least 6 characters')
```

Comment: thanks very much Martijn , you helped me many times previously once again thanks a lot. Here the validation is working if password len is less than 6 it is redirecting to render.login(self.login_form) as i wrote in post form, but i am unable to see the messhae on web browser . how can we achieve that

Comment: @Kouripm: Ah, this is a login form; I misunderstood and thought it was a password *change* form. I don't know `web.py` well enough for that, I am afraid.